# Set SurfaceView behind the Drop Down List

Tags: android

I want to like `SurfaceView` must appear behind the Options Dropdown List [Edit Dimension etc.]. When I tap on Options on the `Activity` then `SurfaceView` should appear behind the dropdown list.

Please check the image from the below link where you will find the problem that surfaceview not appear behind the option drop down list. It will be easy for you to understand the questions.

Please help me how can i do this.

Thanks in advance

Image :

[image]

Layout:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/topLinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dip"
    android:background="@drawable/bar" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/new_quote_imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/new_quote_bar" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/new_quote"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/new_quote"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/optionsTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dip"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/icn_dropdown_open"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/options"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/topFrameLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <!-- ImageView for the product -->
        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/photoImageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <com.amplimesh.renderer.RendererView
        android:id="@+id/renderer_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

    </FrameLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/dropDownScrollView"
        android:layout_width="300dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:visibility="gone">

        <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/dropDownList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/dropdown_background"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="20dip"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:paddingRight="10dip"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/editDimensionLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="1" >

            <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/leftImage"
            android:layout_width="30dip"
            android:layout_height="30dip"
            android:background="@drawable/left_image_drop_down" />

            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dimensionTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/edit_dimension"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/editDimensionValueLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="270dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:background="@drawable/edit_dimension_layout"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="gone" >

            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/heightTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/height"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

            <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/heightEditText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
                android:maxWidth="180dip"
                android:minWidth="150dip" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/cm"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/widthTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/width"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

            <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/widthEditText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
                android:maxWidth="180dip"
                android:minWidth="150dip" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/cm"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <Button
            android:id="@+id/saveButton"
            android:layout_width="100dip"
            android:layout_height="45dip"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:background="@drawable/button_background"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/save"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/pickColorLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="1" >

            <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/leftImage"
            android:layout_width="30dip"
            android:layout_height="30dip"
            android:background="@drawable/left_image_drop_down" />

            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pickColorTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/pick_colour"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/pickColourValueLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="330dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:background="@drawable/edit_dimension_layout"
            android:visibility="gone" >

            <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/firstColour"
            android:layout_width="100dip"
            android:layout_height="45dip"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:background="@drawable/first_colour" />

            <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/secondColour"
            android:layout_width="100dip"
            android:layout_height="45dip"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/firstColour"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
            android:background="@drawable/tenth_colour" />

            <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/thirdColour"
            android:layout_width="100dip"
            android:layout_height="45dip"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/firstColour"
            android:layout_below="@id/firstColour"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
            android:background="@drawable/second_colour" />

            <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/fourthColour"
            android:layout_width="100dip"
            android:layout_height="45dip"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/thirdColour"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
            android:background="@drawable/ninth_colour" />

            <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/fifthColour"
            android:layout_width="100dip"
            android:layout_height="45dip"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/firstColour"
            android:layout_below="@id/thirdColour"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
            android:background="@drawable/third_colour" />

            <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/sixthColour"
            android:layout_width="100dip"
            android:layout_height="45dip"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/fifthColour"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
            android:background="@drawable/eight_colour" />

            <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/seventhColour"
            android:layout_width="100dip"
            android:layout_height="45dip"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/firstColour"
            android:layout_below="@id/fifthColour"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
            android:background="@drawable/fourth_colour" />

            <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/eightColour"
            android:layout_width="100dip"
            android:layout_height="45dip"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/seventhColour"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
            android:background="@drawable/seventh_colour" />

            <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ninthColour"
            android:layout_width="100dip"
            android:layout_height="45dip"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/firstColour"
            android:layout_below="@id/seventhColour"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
            android:background="@drawable/fifth_colour" />

            <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/tenthColour"
            android:layout_width="100dip"
            android:layout_height="45dip"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/ninthColour"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
            android:background="@drawable/sixth_colour" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/addMeshLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="1" >

            <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/leftImage"
            android:layout_width="30dip"
            android:layout_height="30dip"
            android:background="@drawable/left_image_drop_down" />

            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pickColorTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/add_mesh"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/addMeshContentLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:background="@drawable/edit_dimension_layout"
            android:visibility="gone" >

            <Button
            android:id="@+id/firstAddButton"
            android:layout_width="60dip"
            android:layout_height="45dip"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:background="@drawable/add_button_background"
            android:text="@string/add"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/securaMeshTextView"
            android:layout_width="100dip"
            android:layout_height="45dip"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/firstAddButton"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/firstAddButton"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/securamesh"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

            <Button
            android:id="@+id/secondAddButton"
            android:layout_width="60dip"
            android:layout_height="45dip"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/firstAddButton"
            android:layout_below="@id/firstAddButton"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
            android:background="@drawable/add_button_background"
            android:text="@string/add"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/supameshTextView"
            android:layout_width="100dip"
            android:layout_height="45dip"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/secondAddButton"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/secondAddButton"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/supamesh"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

            <Button
            android:id="@+id/removeButton"
            android:layout_width="100dip"
            android:layout_height="45dip"
            android:layout_below="@id/secondAddButton"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
            android:background="@drawable/button_background"
            android:text="@string/remove"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
        </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Code :

```
package com.amplimesh.renderer;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;

import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.opengl.GLU;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.MotionEvent;

import com.amplimesh.AddProductsActivity;
import com.amplimesh.models.ObjModel;
import com.amplimesh.util.MathHelper;
import com.amplimesh.util.Point3;


public class RendererView extends GLSurfaceView {

    public static final int GRID_SIZE=8;

    private Context mContext;
    private Renderer mRenderer;
    private TouchHelper mTouchHelper;

    float mViewWidth, mViewHeight;

    ObjModel mModel;
    Point3 mOrigin;
    Point3 mRotate;
    Point3 mCamera;

    FloatBuffer mGrid;
    int mGridSize;

    public static String objName = "";
    public static String textureFileName = "";

    public RendererView(Context context) { 
        this(context,null); 
    }

    public RendererView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context,attrs);
        mContext = context;

        try{
            mModel = ObjModel.loadFromStream(mContext.getAssets().open(objName), textureFileName);
        } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
            Log.v("DemoRendererView", "loading model: "+e);
        }

        mOrigin = new Point3(0f,0f,0f);
        mRotate = new Point3(0f,0f,0f);
        mCamera = new Point3(0f,3f,3.9f);

        mTouchHelper = new TouchHelper(context);

    }

    public void start() {
        mRenderer = new Renderer();
        setEGLContextClientVersion(1);
        setRenderer(mRenderer);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        return mTouchHelper.onTouchEvent(ev);
    }

    private void drag_xy(float dx, float dy) {
        mOrigin.x += (dx/mViewWidth)*mGridSize;
        mOrigin.y -= (dy/mViewHeight)*mGridSize;
        float half = mGridSize/2;
        mOrigin.minmax(-half+.5f,-half+.5f,-half+.5f,half-.5f,half-.5f,half-.5f);
    }

    private void drag_xz(float dx, float dy) {
        mOrigin.x += (dx/mViewWidth)*mGridSize;
        mOrigin.z += (dy/mViewHeight)*mGridSize;
        float half = mGridSize/2;
        mOrigin.minmax(-half+.5f,-half+.5f,-half+.5f,half-.5f,half-.5f,half-.5f);
    }

    private class TouchHelper extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
        GestureDetector gesture;
        int ptr1_id=-1, ptr2_id=-1;
        float last_x=-1, last_y=-1;

        public TouchHelper(Context context) {
            gesture = new GestureDetector(context, this);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent ev) {
            if (mRotationFinal != -1) 
                return true;

            int index = ev.getActionIndex();
            float x = ev.getX(index);
            float y = ev.getY(index);

            int col = (int)(x / mViewWidth * 3);
            int row = (int)(y / mViewHeight * 3);

            Log.v("ObjDem", "col,row:"+col+","+row);


            if (col == 0 && row == 0) {
                mRotationAxis = Z_AXIS;
                mRotationFinal = mRotate.z + 90;
                mRotationDelta = 1;
            }
            else
                if (col == 0 && row == 1) {
                    mRotationAxis = Y_AXIS;
                    mRotationFinal = mRotate.y - 90;
                    mRotationDelta = -1;
                }
                else
                    if (col == 1 && row == 0) {
                        mRotationAxis = X_AXIS;
                        mRotationFinal = mRotate.x - 90;
                        mRotationDelta = -1;
                    }
                    else
                        if (col == 1 && row == 2) {
                            mRotationAxis = X_AXIS;
                            mRotationFinal = mRotate.x + 90;
                            mRotationDelta = 1;
                        }
                        else
                            if (col == 2 && row == 1) {
                                mRotationAxis = Y_AXIS;
                                mRotationFinal = mRotate.y + 90;
                                mRotationDelta = 1;
                            }
                            else
                                if (col == 2 && row == 2) {
                                    mRotationAxis = Z_AXIS;
                                    mRotationFinal = mRotate.z - 90;
                                    mRotationDelta = -1;
                                }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float vel_x, float vel_y) {
            float angle = MathHelper.angle_of_vector(vel_x, vel_y);
            Log.v("ObjDemo", "vel: "+vel_x+","+vel_y+" = "+angle);
            return true;
        }

        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

            if(AddProductsActivity.optionFlag) {
                return false;
            }

            if (gesture.onTouchEvent(ev)) {
                ptr1_id = -1;
                ptr2_id = -1;
                last_x = -1f;
                last_y = -1f;
                return true;
            }

            int action = ev.getActionMasked();
            int index = ev.getActionIndex();
            int id = ev.getPointerId(index);
            int count = ev.getPointerCount();

            switch (action) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    ptr1_id = id;
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                    ptr2_id = id;
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                    ptr2_id = -1;
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    ptr1_id = -1;
                    last_x = -1;
                    last_y = -1;
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                    float x,y;

                    if (count >= 2) {
                        x = ev.getX(index);
                        y = ev.getY(index);

                        if (last_x != -1) 
                            drag_xz(x - last_x, y - last_y);
                    }
                    else {
                        x = ev.getX(index);
                        y = ev.getY(index);

                        if (last_x != -1) 
                            drag_xy(x - last_x, y - last_y);
                    }

                    last_x = x;
                    last_y = y;
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }

    }

    public final static int NONE=-1;
    public final static int X_AXIS=0;
    public final static int Y_AXIS=1;
    public final static int Z_AXIS=2;

    float mRotationFinal=-1f;
    float mRotationDelta=0f;
    int mRotationAxis=-1;

    private void tick() {
        if (mRotationFinal != -1) {
            float close = Math.abs(mRotationDelta*2);
            switch (mRotationAxis) {
                case X_AXIS:
                    mRotate.x += mRotationDelta;
                    if (Math.abs(mRotationFinal - mRotate.x) <= close) {
                        mRotate.x = mRotationFinal;
                        mRotationFinal=-1;
                    }
                    break;
                case Y_AXIS:
                    mRotate.y += mRotationDelta;
                    if (Math.abs(mRotationFinal - mRotate.y) <= close) {
                        mRotate.y = mRotationFinal;
                        mRotationFinal=-1;
                    }
                    break;
                case Z_AXIS:
                    mRotate.z += mRotationDelta;
                    if (Math.abs(mRotationFinal - mRotate.z) <= close) {
                        mRotate.z = mRotationFinal;
                        mRotationFinal=-1;
                    }
                break;
            }
            //mRotate.minmax(-360,-360,-360, 360,360,360);
        }

    }

    private class Renderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {
        public Renderer() {
            setAlpha(0);
            setZOrderOnTop(false);
        }

        public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config)
        {
            gl.glClearColor(0f,0f,0f, 0.5f);
            gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
            gl.glDepthFunc(GL10.GL_LEQUAL);
            gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_NICEST);

            gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
            gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_SMOOTH);

            build_grid(GRID_SIZE);

            if(mModel != null)
                mModel.bindTextures(mContext, gl);
        }

        public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int w, int h) {
            mViewWidth = (float)w;
            mViewHeight = (float)h;
            gl.glViewport(0,0,w,h);

            gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
            gl.glLoadIdentity();
            GLU.gluPerspective(gl, 60.0f, mViewWidth/mViewHeight, 0.1f, 100f);

            gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
            gl.glLoadIdentity();
        }

        public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
            tick();
            gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
            gl.glPushMatrix();

            //position camera
            GLU.gluLookAt(gl, mCamera.x,mCamera.y,mCamera.z, mOrigin.x,mOrigin.y,mOrigin.z, 0f,1f,0f);

            //draw_grid
            draw_grid(gl);

            //draw_model
            gl.glPushMatrix();

            gl.glTranslatef(mOrigin.x, mOrigin.y, 2);
            gl.glRotatef(mRotate.x, 1f, 0f, 0f);
            gl.glRotatef(mRotate.y, 0f, 1f, 0f);
            gl.glRotatef(mRotate.z, 0f, 0f, 1f);
            mModel.draw(gl);
            gl.glPopMatrix();
            gl.glPopMatrix();
        }


        private void build_grid(int GRID_SIZE) {
            float i;
            float half = GRID_SIZE/2f;
            mGridSize = GRID_SIZE;

            ByteBuffer tBuf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect((GRID_SIZE+1)*12*3 * 4);
            tBuf.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
            mGrid = tBuf.asFloatBuffer();

            for (i=-half; i <= +half; i++) {
                mGrid.put(i); mGrid.put(-half); mGrid.put(+half);
                mGrid.put(i); mGrid.put(-half); mGrid.put(-half);
                mGrid.put(i); mGrid.put(+half); mGrid.put(-half);
                mGrid.put(i); mGrid.put(+half); mGrid.put(+half);

                mGrid.put(-half); mGrid.put(i); mGrid.put(+half);
                mGrid.put(-half); mGrid.put(i); mGrid.put(-half);
                mGrid.put(+half); mGrid.put(i); mGrid.put(-half);
                mGrid.put(+half); mGrid.put(i); mGrid.put(+half);

                mGrid.put(-half); mGrid.put(+half); mGrid.put(i);
                mGrid.put(-half); mGrid.put(-half); mGrid.put(i);
                mGrid.put(+half); mGrid.put(-half); mGrid.put(i);
                mGrid.put(+half); mGrid.put(+half); mGrid.put(i);
            }
            mGrid.rewind();
        }

        public void draw_grid(GL10 gl) {
            gl.glPushMatrix();
            int ofs=0;
            int i;
            gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
            gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, mGrid);
            for (i=0; i <= mGridSize*3; i++)
            {
                gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_LINE_LOOP, ofs, 4);
                ofs+=4;
            }
            gl.glPopMatrix();
        }
    }
}

package com.amplimesh.models;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.opengl.GLUtils;
import android.util.Log;

import com.amplimesh.util.Point3;

public class ObjModel {

    public void bindTextures(Context context, GL10 gl) {
        Bitmap bitmap;
        try {
            InputStream is = context.getAssets().open("textures/"+mTextureName);
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
            if (bitmap == null) {
                Log.v("ObjModel", "err loading bitmap!");
            }
        } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
            Log.v("ObjModel", "err loading tex: "+e.toString());
            return;
        }

        mTextures = new int[1];
        gl.glGenTextures(1, mTextures, 0);
        gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextures[0]);
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);
        bitmap.recycle();
    }

    public void draw(GL10 gl) {
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
        for (Model model : mModels) {

            gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, model.v);
            if (model.vt != null && mTextures != null) {
                gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextures[0]);
                gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, model.vt);
            }

            if (model.vn != null) {
                gl.glNormalPointer(GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, model.vn);
            }
            gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, model.v_size);

        }

        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    }

    public static ObjModel loadFromStream(InputStream is, String texture_name) throws IOException {
        ObjModel obj = ObjLoader.loadFromStream(is);
        obj.mTextureName = texture_name;
        return obj;
    }

    private Model mModels[];
    private int mTextures[];
    private String mTextureName;


}
```

Comment: what is your current output?

Comment: @OnurA. Please check this http://i.stack.imgur.com/z0NhQ.png..This is current output

Comment: ah sorry i thought that image is your reach. Your surfaceview already on behind of dropdown list? do you want that white border to be in behind of options ?

Comment: Yes..Surface view have rectangle like shape. I want it should appear behind the options.

Comment: your xml is very very long and i have difficulty to follow it, can you mention the id of that rectangle like shape?

Comment: @OnurA. In the surfaceview [RendererView] i am drawing this rectangle from the opengl..There is no separate view of rectangle its is in the renderview

Comment: can you post that code? apparently you draw this on top of your layout thus it draws it in front of everything.

Comment: setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0);
getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
setZOrderOnTop(true); ..Please let me know if you need to complete code. I think this code is enough

Comment: i added it as answer since it's too long to follow

Answer (score 0):

In your code setZOrderOnTop(true); i think this explains everything, it causes the rectangle to draw on top, that's why you see like that, you should set that to false

```
setZOrderOnTop(false);
```

and also at your code you should declare your options dropdown list and call this on it

```
...
yourDropDownView.bringToFront();
```

Comment: Now Background imageview [photoImageView] completely hide. Check here http://i.stack.imgur.com/CDHS4.png

Comment: make your rectangle transparent, setAlpha(0);

Comment: There is no rectangle...There is only surfaceview on which i draw the rectangle using the opengl. If i set the surfaceview to alpha(0) then no [rectangle] appear on surfaceview.

Comment: you should set the backgronud alpha of your opengl code not the entire one, and also you should set the setZOrderOnTop(true); to false

Comment: Yes I set the setalpha(0) to surfaceview on which rectangle draw. and even set to setZOrderOnTop(false); Then nothing appear on surfaceview.

Comment: not on your surfaceview, in your opengl code, and also in your code it says it is set to true,

Comment: Yes I did like that private class Renderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {
  public Renderer() {
   setAlpha(0);
   setZOrderOnTop(false);
  }

Comment: at your constructor remvove the setAlpha(0), and in your surfacecrated change this gl.glClearColor(0f,0f,0f, 0.5f); to this gl.glClearColor(0f,0f,0f, 0.0f); the last parameter is alpha

Comment: When I did that then background photoimageview hide completely

Comment: what is photoimageview?

Comment: photoImageView is the ImageView. Please check in the layout in the question

Comment: your layout is very complicated, but what i tell in overall should work.